# The use of "bad" vs the use of "badly."

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, adverbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“I feel bad for you” versus “I feel badly for you”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20412/i-feel-bad-for-you-versus-i-feel-badly-for-you)

Which of the following is more grammatically correct?

> I feel bad for her.

or

> I feel badly for her.