# "I need to wash my hands bad[ly]"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, adverbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“I feel bad for you” versus “I feel badly for you”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20412/i-feel-bad-for-you-versus-i-feel-badly-for-you)

I'm terrible at the usage of *bad* vs. *badly*. Given the sentence:

> I need to wash my hands bad[ly].

Should the correct term be *bad* or *badly*?

Comment: No. The correct term should not be "bad or badly".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of your issue is the placement of *badly*. Where you have it in your sentence, it is trying to modify "wash"; however, what you want is for it to modify "need." So I would suggest this:

> I badly need to wash my hands.

And even better:

> I really need to wash my hands.

Comment: Right, but if you were forced to work with the sentence as given, which one is more correct? Or are they both just equally wrong?

Comment: I think they're both not ideal. I guess if forced to choose one, I'd choose *I need to wash my hands bad*, and risk sounding colloquial. *I need to wash my hands badly* sounds like you're not going to do a very good job of the washing.

Comment: I am not sure what circumstances might "force .. to work with the sentence as given" but, if you are, then there is no sense in which it can be made "more correct"; just a little less badder than it is.

Answer (score 4):

It would be better to say "I *badly* need to wash my hands" or "I need to wash my hands, *badly*". Where the adverb goes and how it's punctuated, if at all, determines what it modifies.

On the other hand, rather than using the ambiguous term *badly* here, you would be better off saying "I *really* need to wash my hands". In both cases, *badly* and *really*, the meaning is that your hands are very dirty and definitely need to be washed.