# What does "You're doing fine" mean?

Tags: meaning

I watched a movie last night, *A Pigeon Sat On A Branch Reflecting On Existence*. In the movies, almost every character keep repeating this line: "**I'm happy to hear you're doing fine**." What is the meaning of that? They are talking in a phone so I don't know who they talked to, but what is "**doing fine**"?

Comment: Related question, [“I'm well” vs. “I'm good” vs. “I'm doing well”, etc](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/605/im-well-vs-im-good-vs-im-doing-well-etc).

Answer (score 2):

Definition of *fine*:

> In good health and feeling well.

Example:

> “I’m fine, just fine. And you?"

So, your example is another way of saying:

> I'm happy to hear you're doing *well*.
>
> I'm happy to hear you're doing *good*.

([Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/fine))

Comment: So that is "I'm happy to hear your heath is good"?

Comment: @HuyVo: Not just one's health; it can be one's finances, or progress on some kooky project, or whatever.

Comment: @HuyVo I think more of, "I'm happy to hear **you** are good." "You" generally.